# Solving PDEs by difference method

Tags: combinatorics, limits, partial-differential-equations

Partial differential equations (PDEs) are hard. Humans came out with lots of techniques and classifications to deal with them, but so far there isn't a universal way to solve.

In this post, I'm particularly interested in solving a DE by finite method. Consider the following simple example on the real line $df/dx=f$ with $f(0)=1$, whose solution is $f(x) = e^x$. One way to do it is by partitioning $[0,1]$ into $N$ pieces, and solve the corresponding **difference** equation instead. Then one gets $(1+\frac{x}{N})^N$ and then the solution to the original DE can be obtained by taking limit.

In general, when the problem is of higher dimension, we can also approach a DE by a similar way. However, one has to deal with some problems

1. taking limit properly .. convergence problem
2. finding a closed form .. combinatorial problem

#### Question

Is there any PDE whose **exact** (not numeric) solution is (still) only known by the difference method mentioned above?

Comment: Yep I'm aware of that. I hope to look for some types of PDE for which people know how to solve by passing from the discrete to the continuum.

Comment: @Harry49 I understand it's complicated. So I ask if there's any known successful case.

Comment: I don't know any case where a discretization provided a closed-form solution that isn't already known (even for ODE). Moreover, it seems particularly difficult to do so for PDE